# View model's List is not persisting after adding multiple elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My end goal is to add the user's list of new items to the database. What I want is when the user clicks "add", the item is added to a list that is encapsulated within the view model `AddItemViewModel`. If they were to add another item, the list will then show TWO elements and so on. Eventually there will be a button labeled "store" and then the view model's list property will have all the new items to store in the database.

My issue right now is after the user adds a second item, the list comes back to the `HttpPost` action method as null and so therefore does not have the first item stored.

View model:

```
namespace Borrow.Models.Views.AddItem
{
    public class AddItemViewModel
    {
        public NewItemViewModel NewItemViewModel { get; set; }
        public List<NewItemViewModel>? ItemsToSave { get; set; }

        public AddItemViewModel()
        {
            //this.ItemsToSave = new List<NewItemViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

`AddItemController.cs`

```
[Authorize]
public class AddItemController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUserDataAccess _userDataAccess;
    private UserManager<User> _UserManager;

    public AddItemController(UserManager<User> um, IMapper mapper, IUserDataAccess ia)
    {
        _UserManager = um;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _userDataAccess = ia;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        AddItemViewModel setup = new();
        setup.ItemsToSave = new List<NewItemViewModel>();
        return View(setup);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(AddItemViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (viewModel.ItemsToSave is null)  
                viewModel.ItemsToSave = new List<NewItemViewModel>();

            viewModel.ItemsToSave.Add(viewModel.NewItemViewModel);
        }

        //viewModel.NewItemViewModel = new();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Borrow.Models.Views.AddItem.AddItemViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Item";
}

<h1>Add Item</h1>
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><label>Item Name:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input asp-for="@Model.NewItemViewModel.Name" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.NewItemViewModel.Name"
                  class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><label>Description:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input asp-for="@Model.NewItemViewModel.Description" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.NewItemViewModel.Description"
                  class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><label>Date Acquired:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input asp-for="@Model.NewItemViewModel.DateAcquired" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.NewItemViewModel.DateAcquired"
                  class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-2 col-sm-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Pending New Items</h1>
    <div>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:33%">ItemName</th>
                <th style="width:33%">Description</th>
                <th style="width:33%">Acquired</th>
                <th style="width:33%">Count</th>
            </tr>

            @for (int index = 0; index < Model.ItemsToSave.Count(); ++index)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.ItemsToSave[index].Name</td>
                    <td>@Model.ItemsToSave[index].Description</td>
                    <td>@Model.ItemsToSave[index].DateAcquired.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                    <td>@Model.ItemsToSave.Count()</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```